# Fastest way to grab frames from video file OpenCV

Tags: objective-c, xcode, video, opencv, frames

I want to do some openCV Video processing. Im on a Mac working with openCV in Xcode 4 so in fact my code is Objective C++.

I want to access all frames of a video as fast as possible (without displaying it and without drops) and do calculations on them.

my code to get the frames:

```
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromFile("A MOVIE FILE HERE");

IplImage* frame;

 while(1) {
    frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);

    if (!frame) break;

       // openCV Stuff here...

    char c = cvWaitKey(1); 
    if(c==27) break;
}
```

I know the speed massively depends on Codec/Resolution/Bitrate - but it seems that I can't read with more than 120% speed... any idea how to grab frames faster?

Comment: `cvWaitKey()` is not needed at all.

Answer (score 1):

Actually there's only one thing that slows your program - it's `waitKey` as **Quentin Geissmann** already mentioned. And if you say:

> tried that already - forgot to mention that. Didn't really speed up
>   things.

Than I don't believe you because I have just tested it on my environment and it speeds up on 30-40%.

Here's benchmark code:

```
#define WAIT_ON
int main()
{
    cv::Mat frame;
    cv::VideoCapture capture = cv::VideoCapture("video/in.avi");
    int k;

    double benchTime = (double)cv::getTickCount();
    while (1)
    {
        capture >> frame;
        if (!frame.data)
        {
            break;
        }

#ifdef WAIT_ON
        k = cv::waitKey(1);
        if (k == 27)
        {
            break;
        }
#endif
    }

    std::cout << ((double)cv::getTickCount() - benchTime)/cv::getTickFrequency() << std::endl;
}
```

Video input: `854x480, 24fps, 2:00`.

With `WAIT_ON` macro: **~11 sec**

Without: **~7.3 sec**

**Update:**

To reduce image resolution in videostream set these parameters:

```
CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH Width of the frames in the video stream.
CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT Height of the frames in the video stream.
```

in [`set` method](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-set) to other (320x240).

Comment: @kava has it improved your speed?

Comment: unfortunately it didn't - there is no video grabbing/playback when i comment out the cvWaitKey(). It Just hangs on the first frame. Seems I need the cvWaitKey()?! I'm an looking forward in finding a way to process the frames at lower resolution. Im working with FullHD Material, but it would be enough to process them at something like 320x200. Do I need to cvConvertImage() or is there another way to 'read a file at lower resolution' ? What does Quicktimeplayer do when I play a FullHD file at quarter-size?

Comment: @kava welcome back! It's been so long since you forget about this question... and now you decided to improve speed again? See update section of my answer.

Comment: the CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME parameters don't seem to work on videos, I assume these are only for setting Camera resultions during capture. I think I have to implement ffmpeg or similar to do a lower resolution processing on video files...

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed several times that `cv::waitKey()`/`cvWaitKey()` is not accurate for short (<10ms) times. In fact, in my case, it seems to sleep for at least 10ms with any values under 10ms. Maybe someone can bring more precision about this, but I would suggest to **remove it** from your loop (if you can).

I hope it works,
Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, tried that already - forgot to mention that. Didn't really speed up things. For me it's not that important that the resolution stays the same - just the frames must be without drops. I don't know if there is a way to capture from videofiles with lower resolution? Since I'm working with very long material - i don't want to convert the files manually to lower resolutions.

don't know if something like:

    `cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 320);
    cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 200);`

works? Didn't do anything.

Comment: Have you tried to separate grabbing and decoding actions in order to see which step is the longest?

Answer (score -1):

The functions

```
cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 320);
cvSetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 200);
```

do not affect the video itself, if you like to change the resolution of the frames, you can use something like:

```
cv::Size videoSize = cv::Size ((int) 320, (int) 200);
cv::resize(srcFrame,resFrame, videoSize);
```

This will improve the time you need to process each frame since they will be smaller.
Hope it helps